# Pass Socket to Module in Node.js using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a Module

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.refresh = function (msg) {
    socket.emit('refresh', { message: msg });
}

exports.lock = function (msg) {
    socket.emit('lock', { message: msg });
}
```

and in my server.js I defined

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
```

and call the module

```
var period = require('./server/functions/period.js');
```

How can I pass Socket to the Module (period.js) so that I have access on the socket methods, for example `socket.emit`, `broadcast` and `io.sockets.emit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this. It depends on how you want to use the actual module. Only one instance for every socket, or one for each socket. I suggest you make your module return a constructor instead of an object literal, like below:

```
module.exports = function(socket) {
    var socket = socket;

    this.refresh = function (msg) {
        socket.emit('refresh', { message: msg });
    }

    this.lock = function (msg) {
        socket.emit('lock', { message: msg });
    }

}
```

Then you can create new objects containing the actual socket.

```
var Period = require('./server/functions/period.js'),
    period = new Period(socket);
```

One solution would probably be to do this with every connecting socket.

```
var periodModule = require('./server/functions/period.js'),

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var period = new periodModule(socket);

    //make a call
    period.refresh();
});
```

You could also pass the io object in to your module to get the broadcasting interface as well.

```
 module.exports = function(socket, io) {
    var socket = socket,
        io = io;

    this.broadcastSomething = function(..) {
        io.emit('data', { data: 'data'});
    }

    this.refresh = function (msg) {
        socket.emit('refresh', { message: msg });
    }

    this.lock = function (msg) {
        socket.emit('lock', { message: msg });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i changed my module in a constructor, but now i get the error when calling period.refresh() that there is no method 'refresh'. Any ideas?

Comment: try return this in the module

Comment: found the mistake :D I have a Mongo Model with the Name Period :D Sorry

Comment: I found another problem, maybe you can help. When I restart the server and the client is connected at this time the server crashes with the error the Object 51 has no method refresh. Any Idea how I can prevent this? And what the reason could be? How is it possible to use one instance for all, when socket is only available in the io.connection function?

Comment: I think I have fixed this using {'force new connection': true}